# How do you use GraphQLList and GraphQLInterfaceType correctly?

Tags: javascript, graphql

I'm starting out with GraphQL. I'm trying to resolve data to a GraphQL Type. I don't understand why the below does not work.

Given this data:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
    "etag": "\"CuSCwMPVmgi8taDtE2LV6HdgkN0/USvbH1nSht52L3y8EP6BIwVRhgM\"",
    "items": [{
        "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
        "etag": "\"CuSCwMPVmgi8taDtE2LV6HdgkN0/xpywjUARlQ0Ai4IucTvXRNCfTcE\"",
        "id": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "zvRbU1Ql5BQ"
        }
    }]
}
```

This is the code to get it typed.

```
const ItemType = new GraphQLInterfaceType({
  name: 'Item',
  fields: {
    kind: { type: StringType },
  },
});

const YoutubeDataType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'PublicYoutube',
  fields: {
    kind: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(StringType) },
    etag: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(StringType) },
      items: { type: new GraphQLList(ItemType) },  // returns null
    // items: { type: StringType }, // returns "[object Object]"... so it's being passed in
  },
});
```

This is what gets returned via GraphiQL. Why is `items` equal `null`?

```
{
  "data": {
    "publicyoutube": {
      "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
      "etag": "\"CuSCwMPVmgi8taDtE2LV6HdgkN0/OspGzY61uG9sSD_AWlfwkTBjG-8\"",
      "items": [
        null
      ]
    }
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I misunderstood the purpose of GraphQLInterfaceType and was using the wrong method. Instead of using GraphQLInterfaceType, it should be GraphQLObjectType;

```
const ItemType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Item',
  fields: {
    kind: { type: StringType },
  },
});

const YoutubeDataType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'PublicYoutube',
  fields: {
    kind: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(StringType) },
    etag: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(StringType) },
      items: { type: new GraphQLList(ItemType) },  // returns null
    // items: { type: StringType }, // returns "[object Object]"... so it's being passed in
  },
});
```

output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "publicyoutube": {
      "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
      "etag": "\"CuSCwMPVmgi8taDtE2LV6HdgkN0/-aZNXBVLYOJwPMdleXmbTlJSo_E\"",
      "items": [
        {
          "kind": "youtube#searchResult"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```